# What's the current status of cryptography export restrictions?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

Let's say I want to add some basic encryption capabilities to my application (without making it the application's primary purpose) - for example, using public-key cryptography to encrypt/sign private messages in a video game. Should I be worried about export restrictions (mainly in the US)? Is there a limit to how "strong" the encryption can be?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: Tthis question is off-topic because it's a legal issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.wileyrein.com/publications.cfm?sp=articles&id=6211):

> On June 25, 2010, the Department of Commerce’s Bureau of Industry and Security (BIS) published [a notice in the *Federal Register*](http://edocket.access.gpo.gov/2010/pdf/2010-15072.pdf) implementing substantial and far-reaching amendments to controls of encryption software and hardware under the U.S. Export Administration Regulations (EAR).  These changes were originally [announced in early May](http://www.wileyrein.com/publications.cfm?sp=articles&id=6081), and mark the first step in the Obama Administration’s efforts toward reform of U.S. export controls intended to expand access for U.S. exporters to foreign markets.
>
> ...
>
> #### Decontrolling Ancillary Cryptography Products
>
> This amendment to the regulations incorporates changes adopted in December at meetings of the Wassenaar Arrangement.  Previously, exporters were permitted to self-classify most ancillary cryptography items (i.e., items, such as **video games**, that use encryption but where the encryption is ancillary to the item’s main purpose) as ECCN 5D002.  Such items could then be exported immediately using License Exception ENC.  Certain other ancillary cryptography items were classified under ECCN 5D992, and were eligible for export to most destinations other than Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Sudan, and Syria.
>
> The new regulations **effectively decontrol** ancillary cryptography products.  Specifically, the regulations add a note to Category 5 of the Commerce Control List stating that such items will no longer be controlled on the basis of their cryptographic functionality.  Rather, ancillary cryptography items will be controlled under whatever other ECCN is applicable to the item.  In many cases, such items will likely be classified as EAR99.

(emphasis added)

So, it looks like video games are off the hook as far as US is concerned.